# Django : How to retrieve latest object created

Tags: django, django-models

I want to retrieve the latest object created for a particular user.

Let's say I have a model:

```
class LogBookPreTransaction(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,null =True)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=20,null =True)
```

Now I want to retrieve the latest object created for a user = "X". 
How can we do that?

`transaction_obj = LogBookPreTransaction.objects.filter(user = "x").latest()`

Off course this won't work, but I want something like this. Is the question clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use latest only if you have a date field, which you have so try:

```
LogBookPreTransaction.objects.filter(user = "x").latest('datetime')
```

Try also this, it can be useful when you don't have a date field:

```
LogBookPreTransaction.objects.filter(user = "x").order_by('-id')[0]
```